# Apparmor blocks freshclam

Tags: apparmor, clamav

Apparmor blocks freshclam.

```
audit: type=1400 audit(1574688195.159:67): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/bin/freshclam" name="/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf" pid=7119 comm="freshclam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

I tried to put it in complain mode

```
sudo aa-complain /usr/bin/freshclam
```

But the problem still exists.

```
audit: type=1400 audit(1574688990.754:74): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="open" profile="/usr/bin/freshclam" name="/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf" pid=7672 comm="freshclam" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```